# Jquery UI Range Slider Lagging Response to mouse movement

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, rangeslider

I am using JQuery UI range slider. My slider handles seem not to move smoothly with cursor but lag.
I am using class="styloot" with my body tag. I found out that removing this class from body tag in my html structure makes the slider movement butter smooth (though breaks my layout).
So I decided to add class '.styloot' to every element in the plugin stylesheet like -->

```
.styloot .ui-range-slider {
  /* respective styles */ 
}
```

Now what I observe is the grey shaded portion that indicates the selected range moves smooth with mouse but the handles still lag. Here is the link to the page --> http://oracle.styloot.com/static/discover/discover.html
Seems like I am close to the problem. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If it lags when adding a class, you're obviously doing something that accesses those elements in the DOM that is really slow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figured it was a transition effect clash between the two stylesheets that caused the issue

Comment: @AnkurMishra thanks for the transition tip.