# jQuery UI Slider: Handle lags behind range

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, delay, handle

When I click on a slider handle there is a noticeable lag or delay before it begins to animate to the value of the range value. This is strange issue because the default settings for a jQuery ui slider works the way I want it to. But I can't find where this delay in the handles position is being set.

I tried removing all the css styling to see if it wasn't an issue with performance but nothing changed.

I also tried setting the slider option animate to false.

```
$this.slider({
  range: true,
  min: min,
  max: max,
  step: step,
  values: [ current_min, current_max ],
  animate: false,
  create : function( event, ui ) {
        $this.closest(".cg_slider_wrapper").next().children(".min_value").val(current_min);
        $this.closest(".cg_slider_wrapper").next().children(".max_value").val(current_max);
  },

  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $this.closest(".cg_slider_wrapper").next().children(".min_value").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    $this.closest(".cg_slider_wrapper").next().children(".max_value").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
    $this.closest(".cg_slider_wrapper").next().children(".amount").html( cg_format_range(template, ui.values[ 0 ], ui.values[ 1 ]) );
  },
  change: function( event, ui ){
        if (event.originalEvent) { // if user changegs it not by code
            var value = ui.values[ 0 ] + "," + ui.values[ 1 ];
            cg_wcpf_add_parameter(widget, type, key, value);
        }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer:

[Jquery UI Range Slider Lagging Response to mouse movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117535/jquery-ui-range-slider-lagging-response-to-mouse-movement)

it solved my issue, for my case it was css transition set by another style file.